# Arm Navigation Warehouse on the PR2

Tags: arm-navigation, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the PR2 I start:

```
roslaunch planning_scene_warehouse_viewer_pr2_real.launch
```

while on another computer, after setting

```
rosparam set warehouse_host c1
```

I run:

```
roslaunch planning_scene_warehouse_viewer_pr2_only.launch
```

The configuration interface shows correctly, but after clicking "accept" it hangs. I've checked that both {l-r}_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory are running (they are actions, not services as written in the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/Warehouse%20Viewer)).

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct procedure to launch the warehouse_viewer on the PR2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11481/arm-navigation-warehouse-on-the-pr2/) by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1342 on 2011-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Lorenzo,

rxconsole should be giving you useful output, and the tutorial may be out of date for running on the robot.  We had a good deal of success with people following the procedure outlined in this tutorial document: [IROS tutorial document](http://www.kavrakilab.org/sites/default/files/iros2011_ros_ompl_tutorial.pdf) .

Note that if you look in the planning_scene_warehouse_viewer_pr2_only.launch file it specifically also sets the warehouse_host parameter, so your rosparam set is being overwritten.  You'll need to edit the launch file to connect to a warehouse that's running on another machine.  So I expect that's the problem - and that the rxconsole output will say something like "Connecting to warehouse..." forever.  But it could also be something else - generally rxconsole will show useful debugging information whatever the problem.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2011-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on 2011-10-11**:
Great, it worked with the files provided in the tutorial. you should update the packages and the wiki. Thanks!